# Does google record and/or parse the contents of every google voice call?

Tags: privacy, google-voice

I've been googling around and am trying to learn more about google voice's privacy policy. Specifically I want to know if Google records and transcribes the content of all of my calls performed over google voice. The [google voice privacy documentation](https://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115099&topic=1708126&ctx=topic) just cryptically says:

> Google Voice stores, processes and maintains your call history, voicemail greeting(s), voicemail messages, Short Message Service (SMS) messages, recorded conversations, and other data related to your account in order to provide the service to you.

There is no positive or negative statement about calls I do not intentionally record. Is google recording them and doing some kind of targeted advertising based on the content -- like it does with gmail? Or would this be so illegal that I have nothing to worry about?

I'm trying to find documentation saying that google voice does not try to parse and decode every voice call. I know I'm just taking their word for it, but its better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear to me that they claim they don't record your conversation unless you enable it. Keep in mind that they warn you about checking with local laws before [recording a conversation.](https://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115082&topic=1708125&ctx=topic):

> There are different laws that apply to call recording, so check your current state and Federal laws before using this feature. Some states require both parties to consent to any recorded conversation, while other states require one party to consent to the recording.
>
> To assist in the compliance of these laws, we provide an automated verbal announcement to parties on a call when call recording has been initiated and when it's been stopped.

If they recorded you without your permission they could be in violation of the law. They want to avoid that.

Could they be lying? They tell you exactly what they do and don't do. If you don't trust what they write, then never use any of their services.